# why increasing of computations processes takes longer on multicore CPU

Tags: multithreading, docker, ubuntu, concurrency, parallel-processing

I run simple arithmetics computation test with docker

OS: `ubuntu 20.4`

CPU: `i5-8250U @ 1.60GHz - Kaby Lake - Goldmount - 4 core`

on single docker container it takes 1.5 to run test (as on host obviously)

on double containers it takes `1.5` seconds each too

with three `1.7` each

with four `2.0` each

and with 5 they seems to begin to work not parrallely

so it is understandable for me why we lost parallelism with 5 containers, because there is only 4 cores.
But why with <= 4 we see growth of computation time?

Docker file:
containres run with `docker run -v <path>:<path> <imagename> /app/a.out <test_name> & docker run ... <test_name_2> & docker run ...`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
 
WORKDIR /app
```

test code:
`testFloat` run 10 times and taken avg from it
compiled with `g++ -O0 -static`

```
double testFloat(Timer tmr) {
    float total = 0.0;
    tmr.reset();
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        float r1 = randf();
        float r2 = randf();
        total = r1/r2;
    }
    double elapsed = tmr.elapsed();
    return elapsed;
}
```

I don't know what else could be helpful so ask if you need additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processor is this one: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i5-8250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html

It has a base frequency of 1.6 GHz and a max turbo frequency of 3.4 GHz.  This means it can run at about 2x speed, but not all the time.  Specifically, not all 4 of its cores can run at 3.4 GHz.  This is probably why you observe a per-core slowdown when running 3 or 4 processes at the same time--it forces all cores to slow down to avoid overheating.

Comment: looks right, my first guess was that there could be something connected with scheduling